# Wazuh Quick Start

Tags: wazuh

I'm trying to install wazuh and I keep getting this error.
`04/05/2023 13:42:25 INFO: Starting Wazuh installation assistant. Wazuh version: 4.4.1 04/05/2023 13:42:25 INFO: Verbose logging redirected to /var/log/wazuh-install.log 04/05/2023 13:42:25 INFO: --- Removing existing Wazuh installation --- 04/05/2023 13:42:25 INFO: Removing Wazuh indexer. 04/05/2023 13:42:26 INFO: Wazuh indexer removed. 04/05/2023 13:42:26 INFO: Wazuh GPG key was not found in the system 04/05/2023 13:42:26 INFO: Installation cleaned. 04/05/2023 13:42:30 INFO: Wazuh repository added. 04/05/2023 13:42:30 INFO: --- Configuration files --- 04/05/2023 13:42:30 INFO: Generating configuration files. 04/05/2023 13:42:32 INFO: Created wazuh-install-files.tar. It contains the Wazuh cluster key, certificates, and passwords necessary for installation. 04/05/2023 13:42:32 INFO: --- Wazuh indexer --- 04/05/2023 13:42:32 INFO: Starting Wazuh indexer installation. 04/05/2023 13:43:13 ERROR: Wazuh indexer installation failed. 04/05/2023 13:43:13 INFO: --- Removing existing Wazuh installation --- 04/05/2023 13:43:13 INFO: Removing Wazuh indexer. 04/05/2023 13:43:15 INFO: Wazuh indexer removed. 04/05/2023 13:43:15 INFO: Installation cleaned.`

I have tried installing it threw docker two but it keeps erroring out. I thought it might be that I did not give it enough ram but it currently has 6 GBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log, I understand that you have used the command with the **-o** option, right?

> 05/04/2023 13:42:25 INFO: Removing Wazuh indexer.

With this piece of log, we cannot know a priori what the problem is since it can be due to multiple causes. In principle, it would be necessary to see the file **/var/log/wazuh-install.log**, since the cause of the problem must be registered there. Please, it would be necessary for you to provide us with the log file as well as some information to try to reproduce your problem:

- OS used (Ubuntu 20, CentOS 7, ...)
- Full command used
- What components were installed in the system before using the Wazuh installation assistant and what version they had
- Log file

Some things you can do would be:

- Uninstall all previous system components

  - bash wazuh-install.sh -u
  - rm -rf /var/lib/wazuh-indexer
- Clear the system package cache in case any cached package is corrupted

  - Ubuntu: **apt clean**
  - CentOS: **yum clean packages**

Comment: apt clean fixed the issue.